# In Spring, how do I use a ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to get an EntityManager?

Tags: spring, entitymanager

With Spring I can autowire a bean with the following property:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="foo") private EntityManager em;
```

Using the following I can manually autowire the bean "someBean":

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = 
      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
AutowireCapableBeanFactory fac = ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
fac.autowireBean(someBean);
```

However, I can't figure out how to directly get a particular EntityManager. The use case is that I want to write a test that will get all EntityManager objects and execute simple queries in them to ensure that they are set up properly. To do this I need to be able to get all EntityManager objects from the application context. How can I do that?

The following does not work. It returns an empty map.

```
Map<String,EntityManager> ems = ctx.getBeansOfType(EntityManager.class);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling

```
EntitiyManagerFactory factory = 
          (EntityManagerFactory) ctx.getBean("myEntityManagerFactoryBean")
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

where "myEntityManagerFactorBean" is your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

But why would you need that?

Comment: This is a rare situation where I needed to get a different EntityManager depending on values passed in. It's just a unit test which goes through a list of entity managers and ensures that they are all set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

I use the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:jndiContext-mock.xml", 
                                    "classpath:spring/testContext.xml" })
```

The clase under test is injected via the mock context. With this annotated it will get the entity manager via injection.

```
@PersistenceContext
protected HibernateEntityManager entityManager;
```